# USB Host debugging with Android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need to test my custom USB peripheral but I'm lacking the right phone that support USB Host, will the Android emulator be enough for me to test my USB peripheral hardware for this matter?

**UPDATE:**

I realized that Android-x86 (with VirtualBox or Vmware player) can be used for this purpose, however not still sure to what extent.

Comment: Thank you for that tip of using Android OS in a VirtualBox! I wasted useful man hours googling how to use a USB device on Android Emulator. with no success yet. This is an eye opener! I am going to download Android now and fire it up on a VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator does not support USB connections from my experience.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875061/connect-usb-device-to-android-emulator) out for more info.

Edit: From my research one of the cheapest, quality Android tablets that has full USB Host mode support was the Samsung Galaxy 2 (7.0"). Now the Nexus 7 does have some host mode support but it cannot support memory devices, such as flash drives. I beleive this is due to software limitations set by Google/Asus, since they also did not provide a microSD on the Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549) shows how to communicate with Arduino from Nexus.

About an year back, I was able to communicate with custom board through USB Host of Samsung Galaxy Nexus I9250.

I am not sure whether it is supported in simulator.