# Make Android Emulator use physical usb camera

Tags: camera, android-emulator, usb

Android Studio, latest Google SDK emulator. I have set back camera emulation mode to Webcam0 to get my usb camera connected to emulator. Unfortunately, it's not working. My camera works without any problems on host computer, for example this:

```
ffplay /dev/video0
```

gives me camera video playback. When I run emulator with above settings, camera on emulator just says "Unable connect to camera", then closes itself. Have anybody ever succeded with connecting physical camera to Android emulator? I have found some similar problems out there, but none of them has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to edit the `config.ini` of the AVD in `~/.android/avd/avd_name/config.ini` like in this link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-camera-in-android-emulator/ or use Android Studio directly  like in this [Android: How to use webcam in emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012924/android-how-to-use-webcam-in-emulator)

if this isn't working see Lekensteyn's answer (2nd) in [Connect USB device to Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875061/connect-usb-device-to-android-emulator). it describes how a USB device can be passed through to a QEMU emulator. Android emulator is modified QEMU for more details see **https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html**

to find out if your webcam is recognized anyway try `emulator @avd_name -webcam-list` to get the available AVD use `android list avd`

more on passing through a USB device to QEMU emulator is also in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250938/qemu-usb-passthrough-windows-guest