# Vs2017, Xamarin app, in emulator, want webcam to be emulators camers, Android at the moment but will need IOS and UWP as well

Tags: xamarin.forms, camera, visual-studio-2017, android-emulator

Vs2017, Xamarin app, in emulator, I want webcam to be emulators camers, Android at the moment but will need IOS and UWP as well.

I've set the camera permissions in the apps, the emulated camera works fine.

I added the property hw.camera = true
 and hw.camera.front and hw.camera.back are both set to webcam0

my webcam is added and works

How do I get the emulator (in this case android) to see my webcam as the camera?

I can find "answers" for Android studio, and Xamarin studio, but am unable to figure out how to apply them to visual studio 2017.

[image]

Comment: Did you used webcam in labtop  or connected by USB? You can set `hw.camera.back` to webcam0, `hw.camera.front` to emulated, do not set the same result for back and front

Comment: if I set one , front or back to webcam0, and the other to emulated, I get the emulated camera, if I set either of webcam0 and the other to none, I get the same error, that says the camera can't be accessed. what am I missing to get the camera over usb to work? Thanks,

Comment: Leon, I tried the Xamarin camera sample and it does the same thing. Is there a walkthrough with the steps to set up the web cam to work properly as a camera in the Xamarin Vs2017 emulator?

Comment: Did you clear the Camera's app's cache & data then re-boot the eumlator? My laptop have third-part software to close the camera.

Comment: where is the cameras app cache?

Comment: Open the app info like this image https://imgur.com/a/45YPmzA, can you use this webcam in android studio? Firstly, you could makes emulator of android studio to use the webcam, then run this emulator in VS. If you could use emulator in android studio, you can try to set the same SDK folder, as long as  VS and AS is using the same SDK folder, AS could use webcam, VS should use it normally.

Comment: Okay, how do I make the webcam work in Android studio?

Comment: First of all you could install AS.To exclude SDK issue, please set AS use another SDK  ,If the emulator cannot use webcam, you can refer to this linkhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699625/make-android-emulator-use-physical-usb-camera/44737436#44737436