# How to access webcam connected using USB in Android AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, webcam

I am trying to access Webcam(connected using USB)from the android studio AVD. I have selected "webcam0" in avd camera setting but it is taking the laptop's default camera. I want to access the webcam that is connected using USB. Any idea, please?
[Android studio AVD camera settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSkXQ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699625/make-android-emulator-use-physical-usb-camera

Comment: @null_override, Yes, solved the issue with the following link.Thank you very much. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Answer (score 6):

I have solved the issue using the link below.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

It worked with windows and the steps are-

1. Start the emulator
   command: `cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
2. Check the Available AVD and webcams

   List of AVDs:: `emulator -list-avds`

   Webcam Lists:  `emulator @AVD_NAME_FROM_THE_ABOVE_LIST -webcam-list`
3. Run AVD by assigning a specific camera from the list of available webcams

   `emulator @AVD_NAME_FROM_THE_ABOVE_LIST -camera-back webcam1`
   Here **webcam1** is assigned to the back camera. The front camera can also be changed with the command below.

```
emulator @AVD_NAME_FROM_THE_ABOVE_LIST -camera-front webcam1
```