# USB camera on .net maui camera.maui

Tags: camera, maui, usb-camera

does anyone have any idea how could i connect to usb camera on android using .net maui framework. I did tried **camera.maui** and i can not see it in the id list... I only get the front and a back camera. The library for these two is amazing with many features, but i need all this functions on a usb web camera connected to android....

I tried to connect the camera to a phone and in the id list it doesn't see it, it only sees inbuilt cameras. If i use a usb permission and i see the camera on a list of connected devices.

Comment: https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/external-usb-cameras

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access webcam connected using USB in Android AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951011/how-to-access-webcam-connected-using-usb-in-android-avd)