# Can the MIDI communication be tested between Android Emulator and a plugged piano to the computer?

Tags: android, android-emulator, midi

I'm reading through the documentation, it is not clear to me if when testing the transmission of MIDI data between App and Piano, an external android device is needed. To be more precise, Do I need to develop first, port the app into the smartphone, and then testing? or, can I simply plug the piano to the computer and the emulator will recognize it?

This will help me decide if I should manage a cable Smartphone-piano or Piano-computer.

Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Related: [Connect USB device to Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7875061/295004) Based on the comments, looks like someone had to rebuild the kernel.